# expected value of random variable and sum

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Consider a sequence of random variables $(Z_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}.$ I want to calculate: $$E\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} Z_k \right)^2.$$

Is there any formula, that the result is something like: $Var(...) + Cov(...)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, an obvious first step is

$$\Bbb E\bigg[\bigg(\sum_{k=0}^\infty Z_k\bigg)^2\bigg] = \text{Var}\bigg(\sum_{k=0}^\infty Z_k\bigg) + \Bbb E\bigg[\sum_{k=0}^\infty Z_k\bigg]^2$$

But beyond that, we will need to know a bit more about the convergence of this sequence of random variables, since you have an infinite sum.

Assuming that the random variables are sufficiently well-behaved (in some sense), then

$$\Bbb E\bigg[\bigg(\sum_{k=0}^\infty Z_k\bigg)^2\bigg] = \Bbb E\bigg[\sum_{i=0}^\infty\sum_{j=0}^\infty Z_iZ_j \bigg] = \sum_{i=0}^\infty\sum_{j=0}^\infty \Bbb E\big[Z_iZ_j\big] = \sum_{i=0}^\infty\sum_{j=0}^\infty \Big(\text{Cov}\big(Z_i,Z_j\big) + \Bbb E\big[Z_i\big]\Bbb E\big[Z_j\big]\Big)$$

where of course

$$\text{Cov}\big(Z_i,Z_i\big) = \text{Var}\big(Z_i\big)$$

when the two indices are the same.

Comment: Thank you. Now I know where I made my mistake. Thank you very much:)